# How can I start SQL Server Browser?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I've installed 2008 Express, named SQLEXPRESS and I need SQL Server Browser up and running, but how can I do this?

I've tried to set the startup mode to "Automatic" but when I click to save it stats that the service can not be started, because the it is deactivated or because it does not have any devices attached (roughly translated).

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue too.

In order to make this work go into Sql Sever Config Manager.

1. Stop the SQL Server service (this is important)
2. Right click on SQL Server Browser --> Properties
3. Select Automatic in the drop-down under start mode in the services
   tab
4. Apply
5. Start both services

Your mistake is probably that you didn't stop the SQL Server associated to the Browser.

Cheers,
D.